# Predicates composition in c++

Tags: c++, functional-programming

There is this utillity function adaptor factory called [not_fn](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn), it produces negation of n-ary predicate. My idea is to implement the rest of boolean operations for predicates. The way i try to implement it is to write general composition like so:

```
template <class PredicateA, class PredicateB, class Composer>
struct compose {
   public:
    constexpr explicit compose(PredicateA lhs,
                               PredicateB rhs,
                               Composer comp)
        : _lhs(std::move(lhs)),
          _rhs(std::move(rhs)),
          _comp(std::move(comp)) {
    }

    template <class... Args>
    requires std::predicate<PredicateA, Args...> and
        std::predicate<PredicateB, Args...>
    constexpr bool operator()(Args &&...args) const noexcept {
        return _comp(std::invoke(_lhs, args...),
                     std::invoke(_rhs, args...));
    }

   private:
    PredicateA _lhs;
    PredicateB _rhs;
    Composer _comp;
};
```

And then to define helper functions like:

```
template <class PF, class PS>
constexpr auto and_fn(PF p1, PS p2) {
    return compose(p1, p2, [](bool l, bool r) { return l and r; });
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Will this be efficient, and how to completly (nearly completly) reduce runtime overhead?
2. Can I constrain predicate in template parameters of `compose`?
3. Can I implement `operator&&` insted of `and_fn`? The problem with this is that I do not know how to constrain a type to be a predicate without knowing argument types.
4. Question not directly related to topic: How to pass `operator&&` into the function e.g in `and_fn` there is lambda `[](bool l, bool r) { return l and r; }` is there a way to pass booleans `operator&&` instead of that lambda?

Comment: Suggest breaking it up to 3-4 questions (2 and 3 are related). People answering one might not be the same who answer the other.

Comment: @lorro Can you please suggest me the names of topics, and should i duplicate same code for each question?

Comment: main question is name /1, /2, /3 and 1-2 words on the subtopic. To be clear: these are interesting questions, it's only too broad together.

Comment: You can always design your class similar to [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) and provide defaults for `Composer` and the `comp` constructor parameter. You may want to mark the member variables with [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) btw.